# How to add multiple sendEmailAction controls to semantic:DetailPage

Tags: sapui5

I want to use more than one sendEmailActions but it doesn't work. The documentation doesn't contain any hint that the number is limited

```
<semantic:sendEmailAction> 
    <semantic:SendEmailAction id="shareEmail" press="onShareEmailPress"/>     
</semantic:sendEmailAction>
```

How can I use more than one sendEmailAction?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to add more than one SendEmailAction control as the corresponding aggregation `sendEmailAction` does not allow multiple child controls. You can check this in the coding of [DetailPage](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.m/src/sap/m/semantic/DetailPage.js) (line 156) or [FullscreenPage](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.m/src/sap/m/semantic/FullscreenPage.js) (line 153).

You could use custom content for the ShareMenu to add more buttons.

```
<semantic:customShareMenuContent>
    <Button text="CustomEmailBtn1" icon="sap-icon://email" press="onPress"/>
    <Button text="CustomEmailBtn2" icon="sap-icon://email" press="onPress"/>
</semantic:customShareMenuContent>
```